# Can not refresh provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode

Why I can not refresh provisioning profiles?

I try doing it with:

Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->Provisioning profiles-> Press refresh button

But got message:
"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

It is happening after updating my Mac OS to 10.9.3

Comment: Same with our accounts, it worked a few hours ago. I guess Apple messed it up. You can try to download the profiles and drag them to Xcode.

Comment: Same issue here. I agree with @MarcusFranzen, looks like Apple messed something up...

Comment: This is happening again with Xcode-Beta3 right now

Comment: I tried Xcode 6 beta 3 and Xcode 5, same issue

Answer (score 0):

On one of my app's project I ran this command on the terminal in my app directory

plutil file-name.plist

Assuming file-name is the name of your apps's .plist. This command cleans your .plist and formats it in the correct format.

After that I was able to generate and refresh my provisional profiles within Xcode.